# Error with npm install after upgrading to Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm updating *Angular 5* to *Angular 6* with `ng upgrade` and the error below occurred. I removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and executed `npm install` again, but the error is the same:

```
TypeError: ts.formatting.RulesProvider is not a constructor
    at getRuleProvider (C:\Users\MarçalGómez\Documents\WebApp\node_modules\typescript-formatter\lib\formatter.ts:22:28)
    at Object.format [as default] (C:\Users\MarçalGómez\Documents\WebApp\node_modules\typescript-formatter\lib\formatter.ts:14:67)
    at C:\Users\MarçalGómez\Documents\WebApp\node_modules\typescript-formatter\lib\index.ts:172:42
    at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! default@0.0.0 tsformat: `tsfmt -r`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the default@0.0.0 tsformat script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MarçalGómez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-04T15_27_51_987Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! default@0.0.0 postinstall: `npm run tsformat`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the default@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MarçalGómez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-04T15_27_52_026Z-debug.log
```

Any idea? I also tried updating npm with no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the parameters `postinstall` and `tsformat` from package.json

These parameters are not present in the new projects created by the cli, so I removed them and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of others also you need to fix.

Check the below steps to have a smooth upgrade from Angular 5 to Angular 6. These provides details on issues you encounter during upgrade and how to resolve them.

- Update your node version to 8 or above and Install Angular cli latest
  globally by npm i -g @angular/cli@latest.
- Angular 6 uses angular.json as configuration file instead of .anguar-cli.json. Also tslint has been changed. Check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace for
  latest configuration details. You have to move any of your existing
  configuration to new configuration file.
- To do this create another
  dummy project with latest cli using ng new ‘your-project’ and same
  defaults such as prefix, style etc you used earlier for your project.
  Create new project with cli
  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new
- Use
  https://update.angular.io/ to check what has been changed from your
  current version of Angular → Angular 6. It provides usage of how to
  change/fix them.
- Follow the steps above and copy/update the
  angular.json file created in step2. Do npm i in your project to get
  all dependencies and do npm update
- Now comes the big part. RxJS
  upgrade and resolving conflicts. RxJS has standardised imports of
  operators and Observable creators with this release. Do npm i -g
  rxjs-tslint and add below lint configuration in tslint.json

```js
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/rxjs-tslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "rxjs-collapse-imports": true,
    "rxjs-pipeable-operators-only": true,
    "rxjs-no-static-observable-methods": true,
    "rxjs-proper-imports": true
  }
}
```

- Now run ng lint --fix. This fixes few items but most of the remaining issues will be highlighted and you have to fix it manually.

**Operators Name change:**

```
do -> tap, 
catch -> catchError, 
switch -> switchAll, 
finally -> finalize
```

**All operators moved to rxjs/operators**

```
import { map, filter, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Observable creation methods are moved to rxjs**

```
   import { Observable, Subject, of, from } from 'rxjs';
```

*You are all set. Welcome to Angular 6 :)*
[Check my blog post here on how to upgrade](https://medium.com/@uday4vunnam/things-i-learned-in-upgrading-to-angular-6-277e4c9ec516)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue following this guide to pass from angular 5 to 6 https://update.angular.io/

In particular I had your same error at the point I had to execute

```
ng update @angular/material
```

I fixed it uninstalling and reinstalling         typescript-formatter. 
This caused zone.js and rxjs to uninstall and reinstall too, it's ok.

My package.json before looked like this:

```
...
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"typescript-formatter": "^5.2.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
...
```

and now looks like this:

```
...
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
"typescript-formatter": "^7.2.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
...
```

And everything runs smooth